# Redirecting Everything Except One Folder From Within A Subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess rule in the root of my site that stops anyone going to any folder except /myfolder for example.

Inside /myfolder I have 10 directories. I need to stop access to all of these directories except for example /myfolder/myotherfolder.

The code I have so far (which doesn't work) is this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEnine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/myfolder/myotherfolder/)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.co.uk/ [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be amazing. Thank you!

Comment: If answer have solved your problem then please mark it as "Accepted". Thnx.

Answer (score 6):

You misspelled "RewriteEngine"

Comment: Thank you. This has to be the most embarrassing mistake of my career.